# Filter dataframe based on presence of sample in a seperate list

Tags: r, string, filter, rows, string-matching

I am wanting to filter a dataframe with 1212 so it only contains that samples listed in a seperate list. The list has multiple values and I can't work out how to do this.

The df below is called `RNASeq2`

```
RNASeq2Norm_samples Substrng_RNASeq2Norm
   1    TCGA-3C-AAAU-01A-11R-A41B-07    TCGA.3C.AAAU
   2    TCGA-3C-AALI-01A-11R-A41B-07    TCGA.3C.AALI
   3    TCGA-3C-AALJ-01A-31R-A41B-07    TCGA.3C.AALJ
   4    TCGA-3C-AALK-01A-11R-A41B-07    TCGA.3C.AALK
   5    TCGA-4H-AAAK-01A-12R-A41B-07    TCGA.4H.AAAK
   6    TCGA-5L-AAT0-01A-12R-A41B-07    TCGA.5L.AAT0
   7    TCGA-5L-AAT1-01A-12R-A41B-07    TCGA.5L.AAT1
   8    TCGA-5T-A9QA-01A-11R-A41B-07    TCGA.5T.A9QA
   .
   .
   .
   1212
```

list = `intersect_samples`

```
intersect_samples: "TCGA.3C.AAAU" "TCGA.3C.AALI" "TCGA.3C.AALJ" "TCGA.3C.AALK" ... 1097
```

I have tried this code but returns all the original 1212 samples:

```
RNASeq_filtered <- RNASeq2[RNASeq2$Substrng_RNASeq2Norm %in% intersect_samples,]
```

Yet if I try

```
RNASeq_filtered <- RNASeq2[RNASeq2$Substrng_RNASeq2Norm %in% "TCGA.3C.AAAU",]
```

it will return the correct row

```
str(RNASeq2)
'data.frame':   1212 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ RNASeq2             : Factor w/ 1212 levels "TCGA-3C-AAAU-01A-11R-A41B-07",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Substrng_RNASeq2Norm: Factor w/ 1093 levels "TCGA.3C.AAAU",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

```
str(intersect_samples)
 chr [1:1093] "TCGA.3C.AAAU" "TCGA.3C.AALI" "TCGA.3C.AALJ" "TCGA.3C.AALK" "TCGA.4H.AAAK" ...
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! Can you please add the output of `str(df)` and `str(intersect_samples)` to your question to show us the data types? THX :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate the issue. `RNASeq2[RNASeq2$Substrng_RNASeq2Norm %in% intersect_samples,]` returns the expected subset.

Comment: The second argument of `match` (the expression after `%in%`) must be a vector, not a list, so if you are using a list `unlist(intersect_samples)` may give you a vector

Comment: RYoda might be on to something. I used `intersect_samples <- c("TCGA.3C.AAAU", "TCGA.3C.AALI", "TCGA.3C.AALJ", "TCGA.3C.AALK")`.

Comment: ```RNASeq2[RNASeq2$Substrng_RNASeq2Norm %in% intersect_samples,]``` will work for short lists but when ```intersect_samples``` is around 200 long it returns 207 rows, when it is 1093 long (ie full length) it returns 1212 ie it doesn't filter out anything

Comment: `%in%` (which calls the `match` function) searches for equal strings, but does not a partial matching ("substring in a string"). This explains why your example works (BTW, it would be more helpful for us to use a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question instead of your real code (which contains complex column names that may be mixed-up easily)at the first glance).

Comment: How many elements will the search text vector `intersect_samples` contain normally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257850/fast-partial-string-matching-in-r

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK R does not offer a convenience function to find a vector of search strings in a vector of strings using partial matching ("sub-strings").

`%in` is not the right function if you want to find a sub-string within a string since it compares only whole strings.

Instead use base R's `grepl` or the probably faster `stri_detect_fixed` function of the excellent `stringi` package.

Please note that I have abstracted the code and data (instead of using your code and data) for easier understanding.

```
library(stringi)

pattern = c("23", "45", "999")
data <- data.frame(row_num = 1:4,
                   string  = c("123", "234", "345", "xyz"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# row_num string
# 1       1    123
# 2       2    234
# 3       3    345
# 4       4    xyz

string <- data$string  # the column that contains the values to be filtered

# Iterate over each element in pattern and apply it to the string vector.
# Returns a logical vector of the same length as string (TRUE = found, FALSE = not found)
selected <- lapply(pattern, function(x) stri_detect_fixed(string, x))
# Or shorter:
# lapply(pattern, stri_detect_fixed, str = string)

selected    # show the result (it is a list of logical vectors - one per search pattern element)
# [[1]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# "row-wise" reduce the logical vectors into one final vector using the logical "or" operator
# WARNING: Does not handle `NA`s correctly (one NA does makes any TRUE to NA)
selected.rows <- Reduce("|", selected)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# To handle NAs correctly (if you have NAs) you can use this (slower) code:
selected.rows <- rowSums(as.data.frame(selected), na.rm = TRUE) > 0

# Use the logical vector as row selector (TRUE returns the row, FALSE ignores the row):
string[selected.rows]
# [1] 123 234 345
```