# Finding and labeling partial duplicates in a column in R?

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I am trying to find partial duplicates from a list in a column in an aggregated dataset in R. For exmaple my column is like this

|fruit|
:-----:
|apple,banana,orange|
|melon,pineapple,grapes,kiwi|
|coconut,papaya|
|mango|
|apple,banana,orange,coconut,papaya|
|mango,melon,pineapple,grapes,kiwi|

I want to create a column for identifying the partial duplicates in the group.
For example the output for the above table should be:

| fruit | unique_id |
| --- | --- |
| apple,banana,orange | 1 |
| melon,pineapple,grapes,kiwi | 2 |
| coconut,papaya | 3 |
| mango | 4 |
| apple,banana,orange,coconut,papaya | 1,3 |
| mango,melon,pineapple,grapes,kiwi | 2,4 |

So the unique id will have n number of items depending on how many duplicates there are of it. Is there a way to do this with dplyr? I need the code to automatically find the partial duplicates and assign a unique id, so `str_detect` or `grepl` isn't helpful as I would have to give it a pattern to search which isn't feasible with the size of my database. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `fruit` is a string I don't think it will be easy to do better than a function like `grep` or the [`chmatch`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/chmatch) family. You could also try [`stringi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257850/fast-partial-string-matching-in-r).

Comment: Yes it is a string, I'm not sure how to do grep without giving it the pattern, but for it to  automatically find it. Perhaps make the fruits column into a list of lists and then work from within it for repeated counts?